# Java Selenium looping through website sendKeys combine strings together

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, sendkeys

I have a for loop that constantly loops back a website to fill out and submit a search box with the next string from a list.

For example, if the list contains [abcd, efgh, ijkl....], the first loop would send abcd, the second loop would send efgh and etc.

Currently the loop sends the first string correctly, but on every loop afterwards, the string sent is added to the previous string. So instead of efgh on the second loop, it is abcdefgh.

How do I clear the keys so that I can just send the individual string? Here's what I have right now:

```
    for(String value : List){
        driver.get(Link);
        Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
        WebElement input_field = driver.findElement(By.id("txtBoxSearch"));

        actions.moveToElement(input_field);
        actions.click();            
        actions.sendKeys(value);            
        actions.build().perform();

        WebElement submit_key = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(@title, 'Search')]"));
        actions.moveToElement(submit_key);

        actions.click();
        actions.build().perform(); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to clear the content of textbox before write value to it

```
for(String value : List){
    driver.get(Link);
    Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
    WebElement input_field = driver.findElement(By.id("txtBoxSearch"));
    input_field.clear();
    actions.moveToElement(input_field);
    actions.click();            
    actions.sendKeys(value);            
    actions.build().perform();
    WebElement submit_key = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(@title, 'Search')]"));
    actions.moveToElement(submit_key);
    actions.click();
    actions.build().perform(); 
}
```

Comment: I have tried that before, because how the search bar is formatted i receive a Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" org.openqa.selenium.InvalidElementStateException: invalid element state: Element must be user-editable in order to clear it.

Comment: @StevenFang I have edited the code, the `button` cannot be cleared. But the `textbox` must be. Please check you code again and the html for the case the id `txtBoxSearch` is duplicated, and the first element has that key is not a editable element.

Comment: It seems that the txtBoxSearch is a formControl, and thus actions such as send keys, clearing and clicking have to be .build().perform(), or else individual actions will be instantaneous and do nothing. In order to work around that, I have tried to do actions.sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL, "a", Keys.DELETE), but that only gives me a nullpointer exception.

Comment: It seems the only work around for now is to perform Keys.BACKSPACE multiple times, but thats highly inefficient, and the strings i send to the search greatly vary.

Comment: Before using `Ctrl + A` did you try to move to element, then click on it (to get focus)? Why the NPE throw?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Answer to your Question:

Once you call `click()` method on the on the desired element through action class instance, next use the action  class instance to `clickAndHold`, send `CONTROL A` and then send the new text `DebanjanB` to the form control to overwrite the previous text as follows:

```
for(String value : List){
    driver.get(Link);
    Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
    WebElement input_field = driver.findElement(By.id("txtBoxSearch"));
    actions.moveToElement(input_field);
    actions.click();
    actions.clickAndHold(input_field).sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, "a"), "DebanjanB").build().perform();            
    WebElement submit_key = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(@title, 'Search')]"));
    actions.moveToElement(submit_key);
    actions.click();
    actions.build().perform(); 
}
```

Let me know if this Answers your Question.